# SQL Server : changing a temp column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying to create something of which I am not even sure if it's even possible, I have looked for similar things on Stackoverflow and Google, but with no results.

What am I trying to do?

I got two tables, one is called `Book` and the other one is called `UserBook`. The `Book` table stores different information about a book and the `UserBook` has a columns like `UserId` and `ISBN` and `DateCreated`.

- `Book` Unique id = `ISBN`
- `UserBook` Unique id = `ISBN, UserId`

Currently I am trying to write a SQL query which returns all the books, and adds a temp column which is called `IsVisible` (default value is set to True) but when the `ISBN` number and `UserId` are found in the `UserBook` it will change the temp value of `IsVisible` to false in the final result.

My current query so far is this:

```
SELECT 
    Book.ISBN, Book.Title, Book.ImagePath, Book.Summary, Book.AmountAvailable, 'True' AS IsVisible 
FROM 
    Book;
```

Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT b.ISBN, 
b.Title, 
b.ImagePath, 
b.Summary, 
b.AmountAvailable,
CASE when ub.isbn is NOT NULL then 'False' else 'True' END AS IsVisible FROM Book b
LEFT OUTER JOIN USERBook ub on ub.isbn = b.isbn
```

Comment: Thanks this comes pretty close to what I mean, besides that I need to filter the UserBook on UserId = 'Value'. I am going to experiment with this looks promising thanks! I'd give +1 if I could :/ but not enough reputation...

Comment: Great. Glad to hear its been resolved. You can always come back and up vote it ;). I love to help people with SQL.